# Use OpenCVContrib in iOS Project Xcode 7.3

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, opencv, opencv3.0

I am trying to use the facerecognizer library of OpenCV in a project in Xcode 7.3. I downloaded OpenCV and installed it using CocoaPods (Version 3.0.0), and that is working fine. I try to import `#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"` and it throws an error saying file not found.

I looked online and apparently the contrib library is not included with OpenCV anymore. I tried to build the OpenCV_contrib framework by cloning it from github and running the python build script, but got an error. Does anyone know of a way that I can get the contrib.hpp files and the facrecognizer library into my project so that I can use it?

Thanks